# martingale convergences wrt dyadic intervals

Tags: harmonic-analysis, martingales

Consider $[0,1]$ and thereon $D_n = \{ [k2^{-n}, (k{+}1) 2^{-n} ) : 0\le k \le 2^n-1\}$ and $\mathcal F_n$ the generated sigma-algebras by $D_n$. We do know that uniformly bounded (in $L_p$-norm) martingales converge.

In this particular situation, $X_n$ is a linear combination of dyadic indicator functions, and so an element of a ball (with uniform radius) of a finite-dimensional subspace $E_n$ of dimension $2^n$ of $L_p(0,1)$. So I wonder whether the martingale convergence theorem can be proved in this setting via a compactness argument, using the linear projections from $E_{n+1}$ to $E_n$ that "average two averages". I admit the question is not very precise, but I still hope for some interesting comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Martingale convergence theorem can be proven by a weak compactness argument. Let me restrict to the case of a Hilbert space $H$ for simplicity. Any convergence in $H$ that is proven using completeness can be obtained by a weak compactness argument.

The $L^2$ Martingale convergence theorem is deduced from the following result.

**Theorem**
*Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $E_i$ an increasing sequence of closed subspaces of $H$ such that the union is dense in $H$ and $\pi_i$ the orthogonal projections on $E_i$. Then for all $v\in H$, the following convergence holds with respect to the Hilbert norm on $H$:*

$$ \pi_i(v) \rightarrow v.$$

This is usually proven by showing that the sequence $\pi_i(v)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Here is an argument that uses instead the weak compactness of the unit ball.

We consider a weak limit $v_\infty$ of $\pi_i(v)$. It is not hard to show that $v-v_\infty$ is orthogonal to all the $E_i$ hence is zero. As a result, $v = v_\infty$, there is a single possible limit point wrt the weak topology. By compactness, $\pi_n(v)$ converges weakly to $v$.
But this implies strong convergence because the $\pi_i$ are orthogonal projections. More precisely, we have
$$\langle v - \pi_i v , v \rangle \rightarrow 0$$

This quantity is the square of the norm of the quantity we are interested in:

$$\parallel \pi_i(v) - v\parallel^2 = \langle (id - \pi_i)^*(id-\pi_i)(v), v \rangle = \langle (id-\pi_i)(v),v\rangle
$$

since $id-\pi_i$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: thank you. However, I read the martingale convergence theorem somehow another way (I use your notation): given a sequence of $v_i \in E_i$ such that $\pi_j(v_i) = v_j$ for all $j \le i$ we seek(!)  for $v \in H$ with $v_i \to v$ "in some weak sense" and $v_i - \pi_i(v) \to 0$ in norm.

Comment: Take for $v$ a weak limit of the $(v_j)$. It is not hard to see that the scalar products $\langle v, v_k\rangle$ do not depend from the subsequence. Then replace $v_j$ by $v_j-v$.